# Facebook Messenger Link Button - avoid leaving Facebook message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger

I have a link to my servers from FB Messenger that count the clicks and redirects the user to the end link.

I keep receiving this message:
[image]

What do I need to do to make Facebook trust our link?

Comment: i don´t think you can get rid of that

Comment: Most of all, you need enough users confirming that they indeed wanted to follow this link, so that Facebook’s machine learning will classify this as safe over time …

Comment: @misorudedo you have an idea of what is enough users?